# With Spring Data in MongoDB, can I search by a missing field?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

In Spring Data it is possible to search for data by creating a method with a particular name, but the available names don't seem to be well documented. In particular, I want to create a query for a missing field in a MongoDB document but I'm not sure how to do so or whether it is possible. In my use-case "missing or null" would be acceptable.

I am looking for how to do this using `MongoRepository`. I already have a working solution using a Query with MongoTemplate.

Comment: See also [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) in the core documentation for the actual operator this implements.

Comment: I've actually found the answer now. I can add the answer if this could be re-opened.

Comment: What? You mean [`@ExistsQuery`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/ExistsQuery.html). No we don't need your added answer when there are existing answers for that already as well. Also FYI writing *"I already know that"* and similar statements into your question when your original text makes no such mention of these things, is not well received at all. You got pointed to the basics because you presented no prior knowledge in your question. Next time, if you know so much then state it when you ask.